# Rails 5+ API: single endpoint for both individual JSON object and array of JSON objects

Tags: arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I'm building a Rails 5+ API with JSON as the format between front and back ends.

I want the ability to create a single record or multiple records, depending if an array of JSON objects is sent.

Note that I'm NOT using JSON:API spec, but rather the JSON objects are coming as root attributes.

```
# Create a single child object for the associated parent
POST api/v1/parents/1/children PARAMS: { child_name: "Alpha" } 

# Create multiple children objects for the associated parent
POST api/v1/parents/1/children PARAMS: [{ child_name: "Alpha" }, { child_name: "Bravo" }]
```

In the controller I have to differentiate if a single object or an array is being sent.  It seems that Rails converts JSON data to a `params["_json"]` key automatically if the `Content-Type="application/json"` header is set, and I'm using this to tell if an array was passed or not.

```
class ChildrenController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])

    if params["_json"] && params["_json"].is_a?(Array)
      @children = []
      params["_json"].each do |child_attributes|
        @children << @parent.children.create!(child_attributes)
      end

      render json: @children
    else
      @child = @parent.children.create!(child_params)
      render json: @child
    end
  end

  def child_params
    params.permit(:child_name)
  end
end
```

**Questions**

1. Is using `params["_json"]` a standard way to tell if an array was passed or not?  It seems hacky, but I'm not sure of a better way.
2. If an array of JSON objects is passed, how can I still use the StrongParameters `child_params` method?  Currently, if the user passes an array of JSON objects, they can put whatever attributes they want and I'm not filtering them out.
3. Is there a better way to implement this functionality?  I don't have to use a single endpoint for both single and multiple creation, I just thought it would be more convenient to have a single API endpoint that can handle single or multiple objects.
4. I also plan on creating a single endpoint for the `update` action that can also accept single or multiple objects. Is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

In the case you send a JSON array (like `[{ child_name: "Alpha" }, { child_name: "Bravo" }]`) to an endpoint, Rails stores it into `_json` of the params hash. The reason for doing this is, that unlike a single JSON object, an array cannot be extracted into a hash, without introducing another key.

Let's say, that we post `{ child_name: "Alpha" }` to an endpoint. The params will look like:

```
{"child_name"=>"Alpha", "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/children", "action"=>"create"}
```

Now if we post the array `[{ child_name: "Alpha" }, { child_name: "Bravo" }]` and it would be **blindly** extracted into the hash like a JSON object the result would look like:

```
{[{ child_name: "Alpha" }, { child_name: "Bravo" }], "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/children", "action"=>"create"}
```

This is **not** a valid hash! So Rails wraps your JSON array into `_json` and it becomes:

```
{"_json" => [{ child_name: "Alpha" }, { child_name: "Bravo" }], "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/children", "action"=>"create"}
```

This happens [here in the actionpack](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cd30ec1fe54115016d9337b9fa1ba44697ffd017/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L13). Yes, it seems a bit hacky, but the only and maybe cleaner solution would be to wrap all data from the request body into one key like `data`.

So to your actual question: *How can I manage a JSON object and JSON array at a single endpoint?*

You can use strong params like ..

```
def children_params
  model_attributes = [:child_name]
  if params.key? '_json'
    params.permit(_json: model_attributes)['_json'] 
  else
    params.permit(*model_attributes)
  end
end
```

.. and in the create action would look like ..

```
def create
  result = Children.create!(children_params)
  if children_params.kind_of? Array
    @children = result
    render :index, status: :created
  else
    @child = result
    render :show, status: :created
  end
end
```

Of course you would need to adapt it a bit for your specific use case. From the design perspective of your API, I think it's okay doing it like that. Maybe this should be asked within a separate question.